# how to remove vertex , edge or face from CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, mesh, cgal

I'm creating an application using qt creator which read .off files as CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map and preview it 
I want to make operations on the read mesh such as removing vertix,edge or face and restore it .

I created a loop to access darts :
Dart_handle dh;

```
for (LCC_3::Dart_range::iterator it=lcc.darts().begin(),
           itend=lcc.darts().end(); it!=itend; )
    {
      dh=it++;
      if ( it!=itend && it==lcc.beta<2>(dh) ) ++it;

}
```

any help or usefull links to simplify mesh or removing vertices , edges or faces ?
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the remove_cell operation. The method is templated by the dimension of the cell to remove: 0 for vertices, 1 for edges, 2 for faces...

See the doc [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/index.html#title18) and the example [there](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/index.html#title21).

Comment: is there any example of removing/adding cells from read mesh , because all examples about polygon created within code like this:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/Combinatorial_map_2map_3_operations_8cpp-example.html

I don't know how to use dart handle in read mesh @gdamiand